# Manipulating the monad stack

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

If I have a stack of monads, say `IO`, `State` and `Error`, and a function that only uses `IO` and `Error`.  How would one go about "removing" the middle `State` monad from the stack so I can use my function?  If the order was `IO`, `Error`, `State`, I could use `lift` to match the types, but I want to be able to use my function if the monad stack contains `IO` and `Error` and possibly other monads in whatever order.  For example:

```
fun :: ErrorT String IO ()
fun = throwError "error"

someCode :: ErrorT String (StateT Int IO) ()
someCode = do
    -- I want to use fun here
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just change the type signature of `fun` to `fun :: (MonadError String m, MonadIO m) => m ()`. It will then be usable for any monad stack that have a `String` Error, and can perform IO (such as `ErrorT String (StateT Int IO)`).

Eg:

```
fun :: (MonadError String m, MonadIO m) => m ()
fun = do
  liftIO $ putStrLn "in fun"
  throwError "error"

someCode :: ErrorT String (StateT Int IO) ()
someCode = do
  fun
  -- whatever you want
```